# Git ignore files with particular extension in a particular folder name

Tags: git, gitignore

I am using git 1.9.5 (Windows 7) and want to ignore some files with particular extension in a particular folder name.

for example:

```
A\Reports\fileA.docx
A\Reports\fileA.pdf
B\Reports\fileB.docx
B\Reports\fileB.pdf
C\Reports\fileC.docx
C\Reports\fileC.pdf
```

I have tried Reports\*.docx and Reports\*.pdf, didn't work.

I understand the .gitignore could be put in each folder (e.g. A, B, C). However, I have many folders Reports and will create more in the future. Am trying to find a solution in the global ignore file.

How could I write rules to ignore them?

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Did you try `Reports\*.docx`?

Comment: Yes. I have tried it. I didn't notice two backslash is required to show it in the question.

Comment: If you put those sections in code formatting using backticks like so `\`some code\`` they will show up better

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following pattern:

```
**/Reports/*.docx
**/Reports/*.pdf
```

What it means:

Ignore in all directories (`**`), a sub-directory directory named Reports (`/Reports`), containing a file with a docx extension (`/*.docx`).

Notice that the directories are separated by forward slashes (`/`) even though you are in a Windows environment.